# Django project: track migrations

Tags: python, django

While developing a Django project tracking it with git and GitHub, how should I manage migrations?

Sometimes when I deploy a release to production some migrations crash due to files that I delete after this migration.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I think [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/) cover this.

Answer (score 2):

There is other threads on this but basically this is the rules I use:

1. You should definately remote migrations files using Git.
2. Never run `makemigrations` on production environment always in developpment.

Now, let's say you made a change on one of your models (in developpment I hope), you will run a normal `makemigrations`. Then, run `migrate` (still in dev) in order to test everything. When you're ready, you will commit and push the created files and pull in prod to then run `migrate` to update database schema.

This will assure good versionning of your migrations files. Also, it will greatly help you in the long run, because running makemigrations in produciton and in dev simultaneously will just cause more conflicts on migrations files which can be a pain.